# What is the grammatical role of the word "either" in the following sentence?

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, semantic-roles

What is the grammatical role of "either" in the following sentence:

> Nevertheless, a goal is seldom destroyed by a delay, so don't destroy
>   your positive attitude, **either**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an adverb. Here's what [**Cambridge Dictionary**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/either) says about *either* when it's used as an adverb:

> **used in negative sentences instead of "also" or "too":**
>
> *I don't eat meat and my husband doesn't **either**.*
>
> *"I've never been to the States." "I haven't **either**."*
>
> *They do really good food at that restaurant and it's not very expensive **either**.*

I always think of *either* when it's an adverb as the negative form of *too*. For example:

> You like it? I like it **too**!
>
> You don't like it? I don't like it **either**!

As a general rule, if you want your English to sound proper, when you negate a statement, you have to change *too* to *either*.